# multiple index integer linear program

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have a bounded integer linear programming which has more than 1000 decision variables. the decision variable has five indices x_{ijkzf} the constraints have one or two or more summations. Are there any easy trick for extracting, constructing and preparing the coefficient matrix? it is not easy to construct the matrices for integer linear program function.

Comment: For larger, complex models the matrix interface can become very inconvenient [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/10/matlab-vs-gams-integer-programming.html). Use a modeling system like AMPL or GAMS or use a modeling framework provided by solvers like Cplex and Gurobi.

Comment: Totally agree. The use of a matrix-oriented viewpoint is great for some academic thinking, but is a real hindrance for many practical problems. Not that I am criticising 'academic' thinking - those 'academics' are the trailblazers who developed our tools!

Comment: Yes you are right. I solved it with GAMS easily. But I think I can not make a software shell for my code to be a user friendly software just with entering the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done just using GAMS. We can read data from Excel in GAMS. Also the multiple-dimension matrices can easily be read in GAMS. Using Table command, we can import a table to GAMS. Also, we can use excel file. For a multidimensional table, we can add indices hierarchically in excel. For example, for A(i,j,k), we can add i values in first ow of excel sheet. For i=1 we can enter A(1,j,k) at under i=1 cell as a 2d matrix. For i=2, we can enter A(2,j,k) under i=2 in excel sheet.